# Detect bridge Arch and its center using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect the bridge arch and its center using python.

[image: input image]

and I want to like this

[image: output image]

I tried different techniques like contours, canny and other algorithms but did not find my solution. kindly help me to solve this.

here is my code

```
image = .imread(path)
# convert to RGB
image = .cvtColor(image, .COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# convert to grayscale
gray = .cvtColor(image, .COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# create a binary thresholded image
_, binary = .threshold(gray, 225, 255, .THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# show it
plt.imshow(binary, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
# find the contours from the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = .findContours(binary, .RETR_TREE, .CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw all contours
image = .drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
# show the image with the drawn contours
_imshow(image)
```

Comment: low level "pixel work" won't work. use AI. you want semantic segmentation. train a network to give you a mask of the bridge's side face, or the arch stones at least, or the inverse (the free space under the arch, down to water level, "lumen"). then you can find the apex of the arch.

Comment: @Roberto saM. Post the original image

Comment: @toyotaSupra thanks for replying. I already posted the original image in the question.

Comment: found your source and a better resolution. anyway, it's a random bridge, specific image probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you need this for a professional application that will reliably work in different situations or are you just interested in the theory of image processing looking at this very bridge? Why did you add both tags `opencv` and `machine learning`?

Comment: note: I rewrote the "ml" and "cv2" tags to what was intended. "ml" is a programming language from theoretical computer science.

Comment: Did you try to use hough circles detector? Let me know, and I will write you detailed answer.

Comment: bridge arcs aren't (supposed to be) circular. elliptic maybe. and even then you need proper edges for the hough. I wouldn't even try.

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy yes, I tried but that is not working.

Comment: Tried to play with hough lines. It is very tricky indeed. Generic pipeline to me: color->gray->GaussianBlur->adaptiveThreshold->MORPH_OPEN->Canny->HoughCircles. For gaussian blur I used ksize=17 and sigma=7, for MORPH_OPEN I used 3x3 elliptic kernel, and  5 iterations. For Canny I used thresholds 50 and 75. For HoughCircles I used param1=300, param2=285. And I'm pretty sure it is individual for each image. My conclusion is that you have to use CNN solution. May be modify this one: https://github.com/hsouri/Circle-Detection-CNN

Comment: remember, opencv's hough functions do a Canny internally. DO NOT apply canny to the input explicitly. -- hough *lines* will be useless for arcs. and so will all kinds of circle detectors, if the arch isn't an arc (piece of circle) but an oval or other shape